# Extrat Data from DHCP Options List

Tags: python, scapy, dhcp

I'm writing a Python script that pulls data from DHCP Packets. At the moment, a part of my output is just the list of from DHCP Options:

[('message-type', 3), ('param_req_list', b'\x01y\x01\x01\x011\aaa_,.'), ('max_dhcp_size', 1500), ('client_id', b'\x01(\aaa\aa1A\aa1O'), ('requested_addr', '192.168.1.4'), ('server_id', '192.168.1.1'), ('hostname', b'HOSTNAME')]

I only want the message type, Hostname, and Requested Addresss to print. Where do I start with converting this to a tuple, so I can filter out the elements?

Edit:
My output is above.
My code is:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import dhcp
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
runtime = logging.getLogger('scapy.runtime')
runtime.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
loading = logging.getLogger('scapy.loading')
loading.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.layers.all import BOOTP
from scapy.layers.all import DHCP, DHCPTypes, DHCPOptions, DHCPRevOptions
from scapy import route

s=socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0800))

print("Input network interface")
interface = input()


def pkt_data(pkt):
    src_mac = pkt.getlayer(Ether).fields['src']
    dhcp_options = filter(lambda o: type(o) is tuple,
        pkt.getlayer(DHCP).fields['options'])


    print(src_mac)
    print(list(dhcp_options))

sniff(iface=interface, prn=pkt_data, filter='udp port (67 or 68)',  store=0)
```

Comment: Can you just read it or something? Looks like its in valid python format. (Edit: so I don't know how, but I feel like there's got to be an easy solution with Python's REPL)

Comment: That's the output in Terminal. I just need the output to only be the values I want, and no the whole thing. Then I can store that put to a database.

Comment: I have shown you below how to turn that string into a list of tuples. Capture what is now your output as a string, then use exec to turn it into this list of tuples that you can parse.

Comment: you could check each entry in a list of desired entries, with your list assigned to variable `output`, then: `for i in output:
    if i[0] in ['message-type', 'requested_addr', 'hostname']:
        print i[1]` prints `3`, `192.168.1.4`, `HOSTNAME`

Comment: your list is `dhcp_options` right? does the above code in comment not work for `for i in dhcp_options:` ... etc?

Comment: Downshift, it did, thank you! I was just trouble shooting the printout of the MAC Address - but yes! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string to parse looks (and will look) like valid python data strict, you can parse it with `python`'s internal tools

```
from ast import literal_eval
lst = literal_eval(msg)
data = dict(lst)
...
```

[literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse string into python data struct (and its safer that `eval`). `dict` to construct handy dictionary from  that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#At this point it is not clear to me if this exec is needed.
exec("vals = [('message-type', 3), ('param_req_list', b'\x01y\x01\x01\x011\aaa_,.'), ('max_dhcp_size', 1500), ('client_id', b'\x01(\aaa\aa1A\aa1O'), ('requested_addr', '192.168.1.4'), ('server_id', '192.168.1.1'), ('hostname', b'HOSTNAME')]")

ans = []
for v in vals:
  if v[0] in  ['message-type', 'hostname', 'requested_addr']:
    ans += (v,)

print (ans)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the output all ready. I need to extract the options I specified above from the output. The output is raw data from a packet, so I need to filter it.

Comment: I have misunderstood your problem. Your problem is not converting it into a tuple, your problem is parsing a list.

Comment: Yes, sorry for writing a bad question. That is my output. I have a name and a value. I just want to extract certain values ass-coated with a name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is NOT a best solution for filtering, really, but it will works. Code below converts your list into dictionary (directly, thanks @Slam for reminder) and take a values for dictionary.

```
>>> x=[('message-type', 3), ('param_req_list', b'\x01y\x01\x01\x011\aaa_,.'), ('max_dhcp_size', 1500), ('client_id', b'\x01(\aaa\aa1A\aa1O'), ('requested_addr', '192.168.1.4'), ('server_id', '192.168.1.1'), ('hostname', b'HOSTNAME')]
>>> y=dict(x)
>>> y['requested_addr']
'192.168.1.4'                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> y['hostname']                                                                                                                                                                                                               
'HOSTNAME'                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>>
```

This code isn't optimal at all, but may give you some ideas.

Comment: Just from python side – `dict` constructor actually takes exactly the same format as you have here. So `y = dict(x)` will work just fine, no need for manual iteration.

Comment: @Slam you are right. Thank you, i get forgetting, that I can directly transfer list to dict. I've updated the answer.